# Create absolute positioned table with page breaks in iText

Tags: itext

I am trying to place a table at an absolute position in a PDF document and have the tables break into the next page, however, adding the table to ColumnText seems to prevent this, I suspect it's because I'm writing with DirectContent but I can't be sure.

Here's the code snippet showing this.

```
void Main(string[] args)
{   
    new Splitting().manipulatePdf(Splitting.dest);
}

public class Splitting {

    public static string dest = @"d:\\splitting.pdf";

    public void manipulatePdf(String dest)
    {

        var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

        doc.Open();
        doc.NewPage();

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Test");
        var table = new PdfPTable(2);
        for (int i = 1; i < 60; i++) {
            table.AddCell("key " + i);
            table.AddCell("value " + i);
        }

        doc.Add(table);

        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, 300, 300);
        ct.AddElement(table);
        ct.Go();

        doc.Close();

        File.WriteAllBytes(dest, ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this code:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(0, 0, 300, 300);
ct.AddElement(table);
ct.Go();
```

This adds the table in a rectangle that measures 300 x 300 user units. The return value of `ct.Go()` informs you if all that rectangle was big enough to fit the table, or if there is some content left in the table that didn't fit. In the latter case, you have to define a new column, possibly on a new page.

See for instance the [ColumnTable](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4#186-columntable.java) example in the official documentation (that's a Java example; a link to the C# version can be found at the bottom of the page).

```
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
float[][] x = {
    new float[] { document.Left, document.Left + 380 },
    new float[] { document.Right - 380, document.Right }
};
column.AddElement(GetTable(day));
int count = 0;
int status = 0;
// render the column as long as it has content
while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status)) {
    column.SetSimpleColumn(
        x[count][0], document.Bottom,
        x[count][1], document.Top
    );
    // render as much content as possible
    status = column.Go();
    // go to a new page if you've reached the last column
    if (++count > 1) {
        count = 0;
        document.NewPage();
    }
}
```

This is the code if you insist on using iTextSharp 5. If you'd upgrade to the most recent version, iText 7 for C#, your code would be much easier to read. In that case, it would be merely a case of changing the `DocumentRenderer` to a `ColumnDocumentRenderer` as described in [chapter 2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) of the [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/) tutorial. The concept of renderers is one of the major improvements in iText 7. If you want your code to be future-proof, you should consider upgrading.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I might re-post this question but aimed at the iText 7 library. Of course I'll try to answer my own question first :)